# checking state variable right after dispatch action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm currently working on a tic-tac-toe app using react-redux. Now, without distracting folks here with unrelated code here is the issue i am facing.

My board is stored as part of the state. When someone clicks on a cell, i dispatch an action which is supposed to update the board state. As soon as i dispatch my action, i check if there was a winner. My checkWinner() checks this.props.board (which is updated by the reducer) doesn't seem to be the latest at the point i check for winner.

```
play(ij) {
    let i = ij[0];
    let j = ij[1];
    this.props.play(i, j, this.props.currentPlayer); // dispatch action!

    let winner = this.checkWinner(); // need to check most updated state!
    if ( winner != '' ) {
        this.reset();
    }
}
```

Where would you suggest i check for winner?

[EDIT]: adding some code to help with debugging.

Board.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Cell from './Cell'
import styles from '../css/board.css'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { createBoard, play, switchPlayer } from '../actions/index'

class Board extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)    
        this.props.createBoard(this.props.rows, this.props.cols)
    }

    checkWinner() {
        // TODO: please add correct winner algo!
        // return this.state.board[0][0];
        return this.props.board && this.props.board[0][0];
    }

    drawBoard() {

        if ( !this.props.board )
            return <h1>Loading...</h1>;

        let board = [];
        for ( let i = 0 ; i < this.props.rows ; i++ ) {
            for ( let j = 0 ; j < this.props.cols ; j++ ) {
                var id = i + '' + j;
                board.push(
                    <Cell 
                        key={id}
                        id={id}
                        play={this.play.bind(this)}
                        value={this.props.board[i][j]} />
                );
            }
        }
        return board;
    }

    reset() {    
        this.props.createBoard(this.props.rows, this.props.cols);
    }

    play(ij) {
        let i = ij[0];
        let j = ij[1];
        this.props.play(i, j, this.props.currentPlayer);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps() {
        let winner = this.checkWinner(); 
        if ( winner != '' ) {
            this.props.hasWinner(winner);
            this.reset();
        }
    }

    getClassName() {
        return styles.board
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={this.getClassName()}>
                {this.drawBoard()}
            </div>
        )
    }

}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        board: state.board,
        currentPlayer: state.currentPlayer
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        createBoard: createBoard,
        play: play,
        switchPlayer: switchPlayer
    }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Board);
```

actions/index.js (play method)

```
export function play(row, col, val) {
    return {
        type: 'PLAY',
        payload: {
            row: row,
            col: col,
            val: val
        }
    };
}
```

reducer_board.js

```
function createBoard(rows, cols) {
    let board = new Array(rows);
    for ( var row = 0 ; row < rows ; row++ ) {
        board[row] = new Array(cols);
        board[row].fill('');
    };  

    return board;   
}

export default function reducer_board(state = 0, action) {

    if ( action.type === 'PLAY' ) {
        let board = state.map(function(row) {
            return row.slice();
        });
        board[action.payload.row][action.payload.col] = action.payload.val;
        return board;
    }

    if ( action.type === 'CREATE_BOARD' ) {
        return createBoard(action.payload.rows, action.payload.cols);
    }       

    return state;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check for the winner in `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle function as this will be called whenever props are updated on the mounted component.

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        let winner = this.checkWinner(nextProps); 
        if ( winner != '' ) {
            this.props.hasWinner(winner);
            this.reset();
        }
    }
    checkWinner(updProps) {
        // TODO: please add correct winner algo!

        return this.props.board && updProps.board[0][0];
    }
```

**[DOCS](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)**

Comment: Still doesn't seem to give me the latest board state.

Comment: Could you show some more of your code and how are you accesing the state

Comment: check the updated solution, we need to check for the updated props with the current props